# Electrostatics Equilibrium problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

[image]

What should be the value of Q?

I am doing the basics of coulomb's law,can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: It is required to hold four equal point charges +q each in equilibrium at the corners of a square.
 Then ,what should be the value of Q?

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, you need only consider the force on one of the charges on the corner, say the top right, due to the other four. There will be a repulsion from the other corners pushing it away from the centre, so you must pick Q to balance this with an attractive force of just the right size.

One way to work this out is to calculate the vector forces (proportional to $\frac{\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|^3}$) due to each of the 4 other charges, and add them to get the total force. You should get some coefficient times the diagonally pointing direction vector, and the right choice of $Q$ will set this coefficient to zero.

An alternative way, if you've met the electrostatic potential, would be to specify that the top-right charge is at a stationary point of the potential due to the other four. To do this, allow the charge to sit at some other point on the diagonal, $t\vec{i}+t\vec{j}$ (other directions don't need to be considered by symmetry), and compute the potential as a function of $t$. You can fix Q by specifying that $t=a$ is a stationary point of this potential.

To check you got your working right, the answer in the end is $Q=-(\frac14+\frac1{\sqrt{2}})q$.

Comment: Yes,the answer is correct but, unfortunately I could not do.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried following either of the given strategies? Where are you stuck? Add what you've managed so far to your question and maybe you'll get more help.

Comment: I could not understand what u mean by "vector forces"?

Comment: A force has both a magnitude and a direction: such an object is a vector. I specified 'vector forces' for emphasis because here it is not enough to simply calculate the magnitudes of the forces: some components cancel one another out.

Comment: Yes,i know that .Cannot we use unit vectors i^ and j^?

Comment: Absolutely! I've edited one small part of the post to use that notation.

Comment: Can u do for me the force on one particle,by the first method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16870/discussion-between-user146181-and-holographer).